# How to list top 5 custom post types depending on comments?

Tags: custom-post-types

I am running a web site with custom post types. I would like to show my visitors my top 5 custom posts based on their comment counts. I already have some code, but it shows the last 5 posts, not the top 5 commented custom posts. If it's too difficult, it may display random posts. Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="last">
<h3 class="h3"> Recent Posts</h3>
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=customp&showposts=5');
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>

<div class="last">
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <img class="thmb" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php get_image_url(); ?>&h=80&w=90&amp" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> Recipe"/>
<?php } else { ?>
        <img class="thmb" src="images/none.jpg" alt="" />
<?php } ?>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo short_title('...', 5); ?></a></h3>
    <p><span class="clock">  Date: <?php the_time('M - j - Y'); ?></span></p>
    <p><span class="comm"><?php comments_popup_link('0 Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></span></p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$args = array( 'post_type'      => 'custom',
               'posts_per_page' => 5,
               'orderby'        => 'comment_count',
               'order'          => 'DESC',
        );

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

to order by the comment count.